# IP showing through Tor different to exit node IP

Tags: exit-relays, ip-address

When I carry out IP lookups from within Tor, my own IP address is occasionally different to the one showing as my exit relay when viewing the circuit. Sometimes it is very similar (eg my IP: 215.24.13.25 lookup IP: 215.24.13.26) but sometimes it is completely different, why is this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: you should use a match like "mine or NOT mine" IP address. If you're using a dynamical IP-address from your ISP, so it's likely, that you can exit through a neighbor IP of real exit node. And also there's a multi-homed exit nodes, and they can eject you out of any of their IP's